# C find substring in a string with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to return a pointer of a substring in a string without integers or array indexing.  Here is my code. I'm not sure how to get it to function.

```
/*
 * Return a pointer to the first character of the first occurrence of
 * <substr> in the given <string> or NULL if <substr> is not a substring
 * of <string>.
 * Note: An empty <substr> ("") matches *any* <string> at the <string>'s
 * start.
 *****
 * YOU MAY *NOT* USE INTEGERS OR ARRAY INDEXING.
 *****
 */
char *find_substr(char *string, char* substr) {

    char* first_occ = NULL;

    while(*string) {
        if(*string++ == *substr) {
            if(first_occ == NULL){
                first_occ = string;
            }
            char const *a = substr;
            while((*string++ == *++a) && (*a));  /*empty*/
            if(*a == '\0')
                return first_occ;
        }
    }
    return first_occ;
}
```

Comment: Please state your specific question. "It doesn't work, fix it for me" is not a specific question.For example, please describe what your program is currently doing wrong, how you have tried to fix that and what specific help you need.

Comment: I know when an empty string is passed in as a substr it returns null instead of the pointer at the beginning of the string.  It also when "bca" is input as the substr it is matched in the string "abccba"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restarting while loop in c without integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587005/restarting-while-loop-in-c-without-integers)

Comment: This question has been asked at least 3 times in the last 48 hours on this site.

Answer (score 0):

First your code does not work if `substr` is an empty string. Add a simple test for this.

Second: why do you only save the first match of the initial character?  This causes the wrong pointer to be returned for `find_substr("aab", "ab")`.

```
 if(first_occ == NULL){
     first_occ = string;
 }
```

You should remove the test.

Then you check the other characters, but you did not save the value of `string` to reset it in case of match failure:

```
       char const *a = substr;
        while((*string++ == *++a) && (*a));  /*empty*/
        if(*a == '\0')
            return first_occ;
```

Here is a corrected version:

```
char *find_substr(char *string, char *substr) {
    for (;;) {
        if (*string == *substr) {
            for (char *p1 = string, *p2 = substring;;) {
                if (!*p2)
                    return string;
                if (*p1++ != *p2++)
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (!*string++)
            break;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: technically '\0' is an integer constant... I'll remove those, *cannot use integers*.  @Isaiah Scott: do you understand this answer?